# string1 OR string2 in regex?

Tags: regex, perl

In the below example I have tried to force the match to end with ".flv" or ".mp4". That is why `\b` is there.

However, the order for some reason matters. Right now it outputs flv links correctly, but any link with "mp4" at the end is printed as `mp4`.

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(http[^\s]*\.\bflv\b|\bmp4\b)/' test.html
```

How can I get a real `.flv` or `.mp4`?

Comment: us an or `\.(foo|bar)`

Comment: @epascarello Won't Perl see it as another buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With correct grouping, Regex should be:

```
/\b(http\S+\.(?:flv|mp4))\b/
```

In your regex `http` and dot is matched before `flv` but not before mp4. Your regex is executed as `http[^\s]*\.\bflv\b` OR `\bmp4\b`

Moreover there is no need to match for `\b` after a dot since dot is considered a non-word character. You only need to match `\b` after `.flv` and `.mp4`. Also it is better to match `\b` before `http` also.

Also note use of `\S` instead of `[^\s]`